# How to loop through mulitple azure subscriptions parallelly

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying with nested **ForEach-Object -Parallel** to loop through multiple azure subscriptions parallelly and get data from all VMs in one go. I am using below code:

```
$SubsJob = Get-AzSubscription -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'abc'} | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $Context = Set-AzContext -Tenant $_.TenantId -SubscriptionId $_.SubscriptionId
    [System.String]$ScriptBlock = {Get-Process}
    $VMsJob = Get-AzVM | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $FileName = $using:Context.Subscription.Name + "_$($_.Name)_" + (Get-Random) + ".ps1"
        Out-File -FilePath $FileName -InputObject $using:ScriptBlock -NoNewline
        $Output = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -Name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $FileName
        $PSCustomObject = [PSCustomObject]@{Subscription = $using:Context.Subscription.Name; ServerName = $_.Name; Output = $Output}
        #Remove-Item -Path $FileName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Output $PSCustomObject
    } -ThrottleLimit 200 -AsJob
    Write-Output $VMsJob
} -ThrottleLimit 200 -AsJob
```

I am not able to get it work, not sure what is wrong. One thing I observed while debugging is that, Get-AzVM command is getting VMs list from all the subscriptions rather than specific subscription. I came to know that by looking at the **Out-File -FilePath $FileName** which are generated.

```
sub1_server1_980337551.ps1
sub2_server1_42701325.ps1
```

server1 is only present in sub1 but it is being picked in sub2 as well.

Comment: Can you add some brief text about what you actually want to do? It's not even clear from your script and I see several bugs already. i.e. why are you starting with enumerating subscriptions and then connecting to the tenant in each iteration? You are passing a literal scriptblock to out-file when I think you actually want to execute it on the VM etc etc.

Comment: Also, assuming you're on a reasonably new version of powershell, you should prefer ThreadJob instead of Job here, since a new Job will create a new process each time; anyway, add a high level description in pseudocode (i.e. in plain english) what you want to do and I'll see how I can help

Comment: @x0n thank you for taking time to review this. I just want to run **Invoke-AzVMRunCommand** across all VMs in one go. Below 2 lines can be removed. As it was not working so I added them to be on safe side.  
`Clear-AzContext -Force  
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $_.TenantId -SubscriptionId $_.SubscriptionId -Credential $using:Credential -Force`